# Backbone sync with Rails resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

This is a long question about creating database entries in a Rails application through Backbone. I have questions about how I handle the data in the Rails controller and also set the urls in backbone.

I created a Docs table in rails with  title, text and keywords columns, leaving Rails to create the id column automatically. I tried to create two documents in the console, d7 and d8.

In d7, I tried to manually set the id along with the title. It gave me a 500 error when I tried to 'save' it.

In d8, I made a document with just a title. It gave me a 404 error when I tried to save it.

Creating a doc (d7) with a manually set id and a title

```
d7 = new Doc({ id: '007', title: 'Document 7'})
Doc Constructor french2.js:24
child
```

trying to save d7 creates a 500 error

```
d7.save({}, { success : function(rec) {console.log('saved : ', rec); } })

    PUT http://localhost:3000/docs/007 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8215
    XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/docs/007". jquery.js:8215
    Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵  <meta ch…ders</b>: <pre>None</pre></p>↵↵↵↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}
```

It also adds a "NoMethodError in DocsController#update undefined method 'stringify_keys'

Creating a doc (d8) with just a title, no id (Rails manually sets id)

```
d8 = new Doc({title: 'Document 8'})
Doc Constructor french2.js:24
child
```

Trying to save the doc without the manually set id creates a 404 error

```
Object
POST http://localhost:3000/docs/undefined 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:8215
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/docs/undefined". jquery.js:8215
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵  <meta ch…ation on available routes.↵</p>↵↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"}
```

**4 Questions:**

1) Is the url set correctly in the Backbone Doc model in order to work with the Rails resource.  `this.url = "docs/" + this.id`  See doc model below for full code.

2) Should I be calling save  `d7.save()` in order to create a document? I notice that it's triggering the update action in the Rails docs controller?

3) How can I save strings without getting the stringify keys error?

4) Rails controllers: My docs table has 3 fields (title, keywords, text) plus whatever rails adds to it. Do I have to explicitly identify each field by its column name in the params (i.e. params[:title][:keywords]) or is this code below (which I copied from someone else) correct, where only the symbol :doc is specified? Is the name of the param arbitrary?

```
     def create
        respond_with Doc.create(params[:doc])
     end 
     def update
       respond_with Doc.create(params[:id], params[:doc])
     end
```

**Code**

Part of the model code with the url set to `this.url = "docs/" + this.id`

```
  window.Doc = Backbone.Model.extend({

        initialize : function Doc() {

          this.url = "docs/" + this.id   #not sure if this is correct

            this.bind("error", function(model, error){
                console.log( error );
            });

        },
```

The collection with url set to "docs"

```
window.Docs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : Doc,

            url: "docs",


            initialize : function() {
                console.log('Docs collection Constructor');
            }
        });
```

The Rails doc controller

```
class DocsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

    def index
        respond_with Doc.all
    end 

    def show
        respond_with Doc.find(params[:id])

    end 

    def create
        respond_with Doc.create(params[:doc])
    end 

    def update
        respond_with Doc.create(params[:id], params[:doc])
    end 

    def destroy
        respond_with Doc
    end    

end
```

the docs table

```
class CreateDocs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :docs do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :text
      t.string :keywords

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Created some seed data, but only set title. Rails automatically sets id, but can I do it manually?

```
Doc.create!(title: "doc 1")
Doc.create!(title: "doc 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the url property on the model, in order to save directly on the model (rather than through Collection.create), you have to check whether it's a new entry or an update. This code does that for the url property, and it lets you call obj.save() for both create and update.

```
 url : function() {
  var base = 'documents';
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + this.id;
}
```

For the Rails controller, it's sufficient just to do this

```
def create
    respond_with Document.create(params[:doc])
end
```